# Is there a way to prevent git pushing/pulling updates to a file but keep it on version control?

Tags: git, flask, heroku

I know there is a way to stop tracking a file which keeps it locally but removes the file on version control for other developers. I have a dev branch and a prod branch for my flask project on the same remote (through GitHub) with the prod branch being deployed to Heroku.

Both branches need the `.flaskenv` file but I need to keep the `FLASK_ENV=development` on the dev branch and `FLASK_ENV=production` on the prod branch. However, whenever I need to merge the dev branch into the prod branch for other changes to the project to take place, it changes the `FLASK_ENV` variable from `production` to `development`. This happens automatically without having to stage and commit `.flaskenv` because I had set them originally to be separate.

I tried creating a `.gitignore` and adding `.flaskenv` to the file but it's not working as well as changing file permissions to read and execute only but git seems to ignore file permissions.

Is there any other way that could work to handle this case?

Comment: No. That would be an antipattern. And anyway, Git never pushes files; it pushes _commits_.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't use the correct terminology wasn't aware that was a requirement, commits include files that are updated, created, removed, etc. anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... Chris's answer addresses your practical use case and may well be the more important discussion for your situation.  But, it doesn't exactly answer your question; and I ddon't want to leave this seeming like the answer were "yes" but your specific use case led to a workaround instead...

> Is there a way to prevent git pushing/pulling updates to a file but keep it on version control?

No.

There are several ways that people like to recommend, but all of them are incorrect and either won't work, or will cause unrelated problems at some random time in the future.

The solution depends on the situation.  For your use case, it sounds like that's where Chris's answer comes in.  More generally, most solutions involve keeping environemnt-specific configurations outside of git.  (One pattern that's an exception to that, is to have my.config.file.dev and my.config.file.prod, etc., and use deployment scripts to select the correct one; sometimes that works, and technically does keep the configurations in git.)

Answer (score 1):

> Both branches need the `.flaskenv` file

No they don't.

Don't use `.env` or other environment files files on Heroku. They are just a convenient way of setting environment variables in development. Heroku supports environment variables natively via [its config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Remove that file from version control by running `git rm --cached .flaskenv` (it shouldn't be tracked at all, even in your development branch), add `.flaskenv` to your `.gitignore`, and deploy again. Then set the variable on Heroku by running

```
heroku config:set FLASK_ENV=production
```

Comment: Okay I was just unsure about that because I deploy from GitHub rather than the Heroku CLI so I thought it needed the .flaskenv file to build. But I guess I just need to change the config settings for heroku.

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether you deploy via GitHub or `git push`.

Comment: Okay I see that now, but am I able to set the config variables differently for both branches? Heroku doesn't deploy from the dev branch in my app (deploys from prod branch) but I want to set the FLASK_ENV variable differently for each branch. Is there a way to do that after removing the .flaskenv file from each branch? I already switched my local branch to dev and it has value for FLASK_ENV set to production

Comment: "I want to set the FLASK_ENV variable differently for each branch"—this doesn't really make sense. Environment variables are part of the _environment_. Why wouldn't you always want `FLASK_ENV=development` locally (where you're developing) and `FLASK_ENV=production` on Heroku?

Comment: Because I'm not sure how to set FLASK_ENV=development locally if I remove the .flaskenv file

Comment: @nenur, you can still have a `.flaskenv` file locally. Just don't commit it. Ideally it should be ignored via your `.gitignore` file. I have updated my answer with a bit more detail.